# Get folder up one level

Tags: php

I am using this:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

which gives:

```
C:\UwAmp\www\myfolder\admin
```

However I am looking for path until:

```
C:\UwAmp\www\myfolder\
```

from current script. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You could do either:

```
dirname(__DIR__);
```

Or:

```
__DIR__ . '/..';
```

...but in a web server environment you will probably find that you are already working from current file's working directory, so you can probably just use:

```
'../'
```

...to reference the directory above. You can replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)` before PHP 5.3.0.

You should also be aware [what `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` refers to](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> The full path and filename of the file. **If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.**

So it may not always point to where you want it to.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the path? Are you trying to include a file, use it in a link etc?

Answer (score 22):

You can try

```
echo realpath(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..');
```

Comment: I get empty string with that.

Comment: This shouldn't give you an empty string ... Do you use PHP 5.3?

Comment: php 5.2 is what i am using +1 for your help though.

Comment: That's it, clean & simple. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you Dan!

Comment: Works for me with PHP 7.

Answer (score 9):

Also you can use 
`dirname(__DIR__, $level)` 
for access any folding level without traversing

Comment: To add to this answer, the second parameter of `dirname()` is PHP7+ only. It's an integer representing how many levels to go up.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo dirname(__DIR__);
```

But note the `__DIR__` constant was added in PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 5):

The parent directory of an included file would be

```
dirname(getcwd())
```

e.g. the file is 
*/var/www/html/folder/inc/file.inc.php*
which is included in 
*/var/www/html/folder/index.php*

then by calling /file/index.php

```
getcwd() is /var/www/html/folder  
__DIR__ is /var/www/html/folder/inc  
so dirname(__DIR__) is /var/www/html/folder
```

but what we want is */var/www/html* which is **dirname(getcwd())**

Answer (score 3):

Use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

For example if you want to access a folder above the root directory from anywhere

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../myfolder/spl-auto.php"
```

or for your example C:\UwAmp\www\myfolder\admin

```
$admin = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myfolder/admin/"
$myfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myfolder/"
```

Answer (score 2):

To Whom, deailing with share hosting environment and still chance to have Current PHP less than 7.0 Who does not have `dirname( __FILE__, 2 );` it is possible to use following.

```
function dirname_safe($path, $level = 0){
    $dir = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $level = $level * -1;
    if($level == 0) $level = count($dir);
    array_splice($dir, $level);
    return implode($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

print_r(dirname_safe(__DIR__, 2));
```